# How to add a social share button in Jquery mobile app

Tags: java, jquery, html

I have developed a mobile app using jquery mobile ...Now i want to insert a share button eg share on facebook whtasupp etc 
how can i do that 
plzzz provide the code

Comment: provide some code you have tried, so that we can help you

Answer (score 0):

How about try using **Facebook Javascript SDK** and design the login within the jquery mobile page template.